# Batch Processing

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch class which is searching roughly 5000 leads and making a callout to an API depending on lead values.
after the start batch the scope has roughly 1000 records to loop, and making a callout to get DNS website details.
The issue I am facing is the endpoint only allows for 1 callout per second and I only roughly 20 leads are getting updated when it should be approx 250.
I have added a delay of 2 seconds for each lead in the batch to overcome this, however I am now reaching CPU execution limts.
My question is how can i delay each item to wait 2 seconds, and avoid any limits?

Thanks

Comment: Can you reduce the batch size?

Comment: Have you considered Queuables and minium delay (it is in minutes): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_system_enqueueJob_2 ?

Answer (score 0):

When starting the batch process you can specify the batch size:

```
Integer batchSize = 50;
Database.executeBatch(new MyBatchClass(), batchSize);
```

Try reducing the batch size so that you get fewer records in your loop.

As per Jeferson's comment, a Queueable may be more appropriate. You can specify a wait time before the next one runs:

```
Integer delayInMinutes = 5;
System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueableClass(), delayInMinutes);
```

Comment: My batch size is set to 50. My issue is that it loops the scope of 50, but i need 1 second intervals in-between each object in the scope

Comment: @user123417 - use chained queueables

Comment: To get 1 second intervals, use a platform event apex trigger subscriber. Take a look at [this article I wrote](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) for more detail.